# Unable to CREATE table #1113 - A table must have at least 1 column

Tags: mysql, create-table

I dont know why I am getting this error, I think this morning i ran this query without errors and it worked.. I am trying to merge two different tables into one table, the tables have the same fields, but different values.

I am using:

```
create table jos_properties_merged engine = MERGE UNION =
(mergecasas.jos_properties_contacts,viftestdb.buu_properties_contacts);
```

And i get

```
"#1113 - A table must have at least 1 column "
```

DO you know what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 2):

according to [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) you need to specify the exact same columns existing in your 2 tables:

> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>       a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>      message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> CREATE TABLE t2 (
>       a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>       message CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> INSERT INTO t1 (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t1'); mysql> INSERT INTO t2
>   (message) VALUES ('Testing'),('table'),('t2');
>
> CREATE TABLE
>   total (
>       ->    a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       ->    message CHAR(20), INDEX(a))
>       ->    ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(t1,t2) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;

Comment: well, I swear I ran this query this morning and I created a merged table, without specifiyng all the columns... there MUST be some other way, really...

Comment: this works!

    create table  students_merged as select * from db1.students_contacts;
    insert ignore into students_merged select * from db2.students_contacts;

Comment: hello again, thanks for your help, please is there any way to include a order by field (date) when merging the tables and also a way to run this query only to update the merged tables with new records from the other two tables? please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: yes, add the order by in your create..select..order by statement. To update with the new records only you have to use (in that same query) WHERE your_primary_key NOT IN (select your_primarykey FROM students_merged)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] table_name(
   column_1_definition,
   column_2_definition,
   ...,
   table_constraints
) ENGINE=storage_engine;
```

> Or: (example)
>
> mysql>

```sql
Create Table films (
       name varchar(20), 
       production varchar(20), 
       language varchar(20)
       );
```

Comment: While the code may solve the OP's question, it is better to add context. Explain how/why this code solves the issue. This will help future visitors learn, and prevent future mistakes, it also helps readers hone in on what is most important to pay attention to in this code. Good answers are also more likely to be upvoted.